# SSIS 2005 OnError handler

Tags: sql-server, ssis, error-handling

This is very straightforward: I have 4 packages, and I would like to define one Error handler for all of them. I already created OnError event handler in one package and now I would like to configure other 3 packages to use the same error handling routine.

I don't want to copy and paste.

What is the easiest way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you call them all from a parent package and pass a variable back to the parent package on failure?  *Just an idea* - I have no experience with such things.

Answer (score 1):

I think that copy and paste is the *only* way to do it.

Comment: Hmm, that answer made me sad :( :(